# Wrapping C++ class in Python with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig

I have the following C++ class that I wish to wrap in Python with SWIG.

```
typedef std::map<std::string, double> ParamaterSet;

class GPRegressor{
public:
    double runRegression(const double *trainData, const double *trainTruth, int trainRows, int trainCols,
                             const double *testData, const double *testTruth, int testRows, int testCols,
                             const ParamaterSet &params);

    GPRegressor(KernelType kernType = SQUARED_EXPONENTIAL);
    ~GPRegressor();
    };
```

I have written the following SWIG interface file to allow me to pass numpy arrays to the `runRegression` member function.

```
%module pyGP
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "lib/typedefs.h"
#include "lib/Kernels.h"
#include "lib/GPRegressor.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_map.i"
%template(map_string_double) std::map<std::string, double>;

%init %{
  import_array();
%}

%apply (const double *arr, int dim1, int dim2) {(const double *data, int dimx, int dimy)}
%apply (double *arr, int dim1, int dim2) {(double *data, int dimx, int dimy)}

%include "lib/typedefs.h"
%include "lib/Kernels.h"
%include "lib/GPRegressor.h"
```

I believe that I have correctly written the SWIG typemaps to allow me to do this. I have written the following Python test code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('../build'))
import numpy as np

from pyGP import *

def runRegression():
    X = np.random.rand(30, 2)
    Y = np.random.rand(30, 1)
    X_s = np.random.rand(30, 2)
    Y_s = np.random.rand(30, 1)

    regressor = GPRegressor()
    regressor.runRegression(X, Y, 30, 2, X_s, Y_s, 30, 1, {'a' : 0.0, 'b' : 0.0})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runRegression()
```

However I receive the following error, implying that I have in fact made a mistake with my typemaps for the numpy arrays.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./demo.py", line 22, in <module>
    runRegression()
  File "./demo.py", line 18, in runRegression
    regressor.runRegression(X, Y, 30, 2, X_s, Y_s, 30, 1, {'a' : 0.0, 'b' : 0.0})
  File "/home/jack/GitRepos/GaussianProcess/build/pyGP.py", line 337, in runRegression
    return _pyGP.GPRegressor_runRegression(self, trainData, trainTruth, trainRows, trainCols, testData, testTruth, testRows, testCols, params)
TypeError: in method 'GPRegressor_runRegression', argument 2 of type 'double const *'
```

To summarise, I would like to know if the way I am attempting to wrap the class and it's member functions such that I can pass numpy arrays to `const double*` is in fact correct. If not, what is the convention?

EDIT:-
I have updated the SWIG file to contain the following:

```
%apply (double *IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(const double *trainData, int trainCols, int trainRows)};
%apply (double *IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(const double *trainTruth, int trainRows)};
%apply (double *IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(const double *testData, int testCols, int testRows)};
%apply (double *IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(const double *testTruth, int testRows)};
```

and have changed the signature of the function to be wrapped to the following:

```
double runRegression(const double *trainData, int trainCols, int trainRows, const double *trainTruth,
                     int trainTruthRows, const double *testData, int testCols, int testRows,
                     const double *testTruth, int testTruthRows, const ParamaterSet &params);
```

so that the ordering of the parameters matches that of the typemaps. However, I am still receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./demo.py", line 23, in <module>
    runRegression()
  File "./demo.py", line 19, in runRegression
    regressor.runRegression(X, 2, 30, Y, 30, X_s, 2, 30, Y_s, 30, {'a' : 0.0, 'b' : 0.0})
TypeError: runRegression() takes 6 positional arguments but 12 were given
```

Comment: Your typemaps should look like `%apply (double* IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(const double* iData, int dimx, int dimy)};` Note how `IN_ARRAY2` is used

Comment: @Flexo It is. I will put it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If look into the examples in the `numpy.i` header, you will see examples of how to apply the `NumPy` typemaps.

In your case, you should change

```
%apply (double *arr, int dim1, int dim2) {(double *data, int dimx, int dimy)}
```

into

```
%apply (double* IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(const double *testTruth, int testRows, int testColsdouble)};

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(const double *trainTruth, int trainRows, int trainCols)};
```

Note how `IN_ARRAY2` is used

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. However I am still receiving the same error after making the suggested change. 

I have tried both with and without the const qualifier(as I want to be able to pass some numpy arrays as const and others as non const).

Comment: The arguments names `data`, `dimx` and `dimy` must match the names in your header files. If it is the function `runRegression`, you must name them `trainRows` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I have now updated my question with the current issue I am having after implementing your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: You need to reorder your arguments. The typemaps require the specified arguments are next to each other.  You have `const double *trainData` next to `const double *trainTruth`, which will not work. Keep you arguments in pairs, e.g. `const double a*, size_t na, const double* b*, size_t nb`...

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your help. I have rearranged the parameters as suggested but still seem to be missing something(updated question). Also, is there a way to not duplicate the dimensions in the function signature, for instance if we have multiple numpy arrays of the same size?

Thank you again.

Comment: If you provide a full dummy example, I can look into it. If you want not to repeat dimensions, look into the `numpy.i` source. I have greatly modified this file myself to support `size_t`, `Complex` and more sophisticated multi-dimensional arrays with row-pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you supply your numpy ndarray to your C++ function, you are not supposed to add your ndarray dimension information, which in your case is:`2, 30, 30...`.

Instead , just provide arguments like:  `regressor.runRegression(X,  Y,  X_s,  Y_s, {'a' : 0.0, 'b' : 0.0})`.